# Limit paragraph height to height of image in another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, css

I'm using a two column layout for a responsive blog site. The left column uses an image, which is scaled to fill the width of the column, and the right column contains an extraction of text from the blog post.

Any ideas on how I might be able to limit the height of the paragraph of text in the right hand column to the match the height of the image in the left column as the browser width is reduced?

I plan to use text-overflow: ellipsis to handle the overflow of text in the right hand div.

Example before and after image below.

[image: Example before and after resizing browser]

Here's the HTML, and the CSS I've used to set the size of the image to resize as the browser window is reduced in size.

```
<div class="row blogpost">
    <div class="sevencol">
        <img src="img/greybox.png">
    </div>
    <div class="fourcol last>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.
        </p>
        <a class="readMore" href="#">Read More...</a>
    </div>


.blogpost .sevencol img {
        zoom: 2;
        margin: auto;
        height: auto;
        max-height: 100%;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        margin-top: 8px;
    }
```

Comment: Still stuck with this one - can anyone help? None of the solutions below seem to work?

Answer (score 0):

You would typically do this with JavaScript.

Evaluate the image container's height once the page has rendered, then apply the same height to the caption container.

You may also have to separate the "read more" link content from the paragraph whose length you mean to apply the overflow effect.

Assuming you're using jQuery, it may look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var imgHeight = $('#imageContainer').height();
   $('#caption').css('height', imgHeight);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain this a bit more? I'm new to jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/ZGyhr/

```
var h = $('img').height();
$('.fourcol').css('height',h+'px');
```

and set `overfloe-y:scroll;` for right side div

Comment: Thanks, had a look at this but it didn't seem to be setting the height of the right hand div to match the height of the image? Can you explain further?

Comment: Sorry, I've just played with this and stuck a coloured background on the div, and I can see that it _is_ being changed to match the height of the image - thanks. Now I just need to get `text-overflow:ellipsis;` to work - any idea why it doesn't here? http://jsfiddle.net/ZGyhr/

Comment: where do you need text-overflow:ellipsis;

Comment: It seems the fiddle hadn't kept the changes I'd made - hopefully this will work http://jsfiddle.net/rNkN5/ - you can see where I've added the `text-overflow:ellipsis;`

Comment: text-overflow property support only in horizontal direction, for reference see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/text-overflow

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to use css to limit the size of your blog text then probably you can do this by fixing your displaying size like-

```
.blogpost .last p{max-height: 300px;/*this is the height how much text you want to show up*/line-height:20px;/*set it this way that there will no cut off text*/ overflow:hidden;}
```

but you shouldn't use this way. You need to try this from your blog script to limit the text.